# php: not getting a result from my (prepared statement) query

Tags: php, prepared-statement

Can someone point out where the error is please?
I run the below code, and instead of it populating the array, it gives me an empty result.

I have check the SQL in my database and it is running fine.

```
function fetchStatusDetails($cno, $randomPass)
{
    $mysqli = $this->_setDB (); // This sets up the DB connection.

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( "SELECT created_main_menus,created_submenus,picked_a_header_image,uploaded_a_header_image,has_logo FROM " . $this->tableName . " WHERE random_password=? and CNO=? LIMIT 1" ))
        {


            /* bind parameters for markers */
            $stmt->bind_param ( "si", $randomPass,$cno );

            $stmt->execute ();

            $stmt->bind_result ( $main_menus,$sub_menus,$picked_header_img,$upped_header_img,$logo );

            $stmt->fetch ();

            if (! empty ( $main_menus ))
            {
                $array = array();

                $array['main_menus']            = $main_menus;
                $array['sub_menus']             = $sub_menus;
                $array['picked_header_img']     = $picked_header_img;
                $array['upped_header_img']      = $upped_header_img;
                $array['logo']                  = $logo;
                echo "*-*-".$array['upped_header_img']."*-*-";

                return $array;
            }
            else
            {echo "DATABASE ERROR 0090";
                return false;
            }

            /* close statement */
            $stmt->close ();
        }
```

Comment: have you checked the query manually

Comment: I have check the SQL in my database and it is running fine.

Comment: have you checked the array,and to print the image you need to echo with the `<img>` tag

Comment: I have an echo in the block of code that has the array loading code, that is not getting called. The "DATABASE ERROR 0090" echo is getting called instead.

Comment: try to print bind result variables before if

Comment: Ok, did this: 
echo "main menu: $main_menus Subs: $sub_menus Header:$picked_header_img Upped: $upped_header_img Logo: $logo";
It gives me the data! But that means there is something wrong with my IF()

Comment: tri `if(isset($main_menus))` instead of that

Comment: Make it an answer and i'll choose it...

Comment: thank you very much friend :) all the best

Comment: And the same to you, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `if(isset($main_menus))` instead of `if (! empty ( $main_menus ))`

all the best

Answer (score 1):

You can get an associative array in the following way, and I would suggest not using `return` until you have closed both `$stmt` and `$mysqli`.

```
function fetchStatusDetails($cno, $randomPass)
{
    $mysqli = $this->_setDB (); // This sets up the DB connection.
    $array = false;

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare ( "SELECT created_main_menus AS main_menus,created_submenus AS sub_menus,picked_a_header_image AS picked_header_img,uploaded_a_header_image AS upped_header_img,has_logo AS logo FROM " . $this->tableName . " WHERE random_password=? and CNO=? LIMIT 1" ))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $randomPass, $cno);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $array = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }

    if (empty($array))
    {
        echo "DATABASE ERROR 0090";
    }

    $stmt->close ();
    $mysqli->close();

    return $array;

}
```

Comment: what does DATABASE ERROR 0090 mean?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I don't know... that's the error message the OP created.

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted :) 
I didnt want the array with the same names as in the DB, I wanted it with the shorter names which is why I opted to "load" them into array that way. I have since moved my return to after I close my connections. Cheers!

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, glad I helped! The aliases in the SQL (`created_main_menus AS main_menus`) will actually be used as the keys in your result array.

Comment: Awesome, that looks much more efficient, I'll make the changes and use your way!  Thanks again!

Comment: One quick note, created_main_menus returns data of either 0 or 1 (like an on/off switch) which is why empty() was not giving me my desired functionality because going through the php docs I see that empty() considers zero to be... empty :)